# FileNet Bulk action to update security folder property based on folder filed in

Tags: security, bulkupdate, filenet

I have a set of a few thousand FileNet documents that need to have the security reset from the document level to the folder level. Does anyone know if there is a document set security folder method as well as to be able to obtain the object reference from the folder that the document is filed in and set the object reference for the security folder for that document? I would appreciate any assistance.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

FileNet has 4 security levels for each Instance.
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSNW2F_5.2.0/com.ibm.p8.security.doc/p8psa007.htm

1. Default Instance Security - is a preset of ALC that applies to each new instance (but not for created yet, because preset becomes to its own ACL)
2. Inherited from a parent container (Folder) - if inheritance applied at the relationship level.
3. Inherited from Security Template by applying Security Policy
4. Own (documents) ACL

The authorization process is calculation of the result permission by applying all ACL (own and inherited).

So if you need change (reset) security for set of documents you have few ways to do this:

1. If you need add allow (or deny is needed) permissions to somebody for these documents you can manually add new access permission to the root folder which contains all that documents and apply this record to all child objects. It will work only if documents or folders under the root does not have Deny records (because Deny overwrites Allow)
2. You can select all those documents by Query and apply bulk modification script (handler) and set exactly needed ACL for each document or clear it.
   https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSNW2F_5.2.0/com.ibm.p8.ce.admin.tasks.doc/p8pcc193.htm